# USB3.0 v4l2 "no space left on device" error with multiple cameras

Tags: usb, v4l2

I have an application that needs several USB cameras.  I know about the limitations of USB2.0's bandwidth, and have worked through a misunderstanding I had regarding USB2.0 devices on the USB3.0 bus (see my previous question: [How to run USB2.0 devices on a USB3.0 hub and get USB3.0 bandwdith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46116696/how-to-run-usb2-0-devices-on-a-usb3-0-hub-and-get-usb3-0-bandwdith)).

Now I am running with all USB3.0 cameras on a 3.0 bus and I find that even at very low resolution (160x120,MJPG) I still get the "no space left on device" error when attempting to connect a second camera.  This is actually worse than when I run on a USB2.0 bus.

Note that I can run with one USB3.0 camera in 4K mode (4096x2160,MJPG) which certainly uses more bus bandwidth than two 160x120,MJPG streams would.  So it doesn't appear to be a bandwidth limitation; its more like USB3.0 just doesn't want to connect more than one USB3.0 camera.  I'm working with a Logitech BRIO.

Any ideas what I may be doing wrong?  I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, and using v4l2 API directly.

Comment: Yes, its entirely about programming.  I have a v4l2 application (C++) that doesn't work with 3.0 cameras.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at linux driver for both: logitech BRIO usb driver and V4L2. Look for ENOSPC status - where it is returned and in what circumstrances. It is possible that driver for this camera is badly written and allows to connect only one of it - and it returns ENOSPC when you connect second camera.